# how to loop through a number of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have lets say 5 models.

```
Thread
Poll
Message
Wall
Zone
```

I would like something where I can loop through each model contained in the string or array, and if that model has a user_id field, update it to whatever I'd like to set it to.

Any Idea on how you can do something like

```
[Thread.where(:user_id => XXX)].each do |model|
 ...
end
```

Where Thread is looped through in a list of models ["Thread", "Poll", ....]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
models = ["Thread", "Poll", ....]

models.each do |model|
  model = model.constantize
  if model.columns.map(&:name).include?("user_id")
    model.where(:user_id => my_user_id).each do |m|
      do_stuff_with(m)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this doesn't check whether or not the `user_id` exists (as expected by asker) which may lead to a crash..

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution:

```
user_id = 1
[Thread, Poll, Message, Wall].each do |kind|
  if kind.columns.find {|column| column.name == 'user_id'}
    kind.update_all( :user_id => user_id )
  end
end
```

But this updates the whole database. Are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
[Thread, Poll, ...].each do |klass|
  if klass.columns.map(&:name).include? "user_id"
    klass.where(:user_id => user_id).all.each do |instance|
      #do what you need here
    end
  end
end
```